# Proof-explanation: $ \left(\frac{1}{n}-n\right)_{n}$ tends to $-\infty \text { as } n \rightarrow \infty$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, proof-explanation

Question:
$
\left(\frac{1}{n}-n\right)_{n}$ tends to
$-\infty \text { as } n \rightarrow \infty$

I found a proof that I don't understand. Are there any steps missing or is it incorrect...?

Proof Given:-

Let $K \in \mathbb{R}$. Then set $N \in \mathbb{N}$ so that $N>1-K$. So $n \geqslant N$ implies
$$
x_{n}=\frac{1}{n}-n \leqslant 1-N<K  [QED]
$$
I'm not able to understand how $N>1-K$

While attempting, I instead got the condition $\left(\sqrt{\frac{k^{2}}{4}+1}-\frac{k}{2}\right) <  N$   (I can prove it if requested/needed)

It could be that my condition is the 'optimal' one and that the other is an approximation (which  would make both valid as an inequality) but I'm failing to correlate the two or where to make the approximation.

Comment: Could you clarify what the subscript $n$ on $\left(\frac{1}{n}-n\right)$ should be taken to mean?

Comment: @Tamay The question is an example in my Prof.'s notes. He's explained it to mean "a standard sequence notation" afaik.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you're able to see why such an $N$ exists, but not why we chose it?

Comment: so long as $1- K \ge \sqrt{\frac {k^2}4 + 1}-\frac k2$ you don't have any problem.

Comment: The $N$ is a choice which depends of course on $K$. For instance, you may take $N$ as the integer part of $K$ minus 1 in the proof you quoted in the OP. The $N$ need not be optimal.

Comment: For any $k$ let $W_k = \{N| n>N \implies \frac 1n-n < k\}$.  To show that $\frac 1n -n \to -\infty$ we must show that $W_k$ is not empty.  We do *not* have to calculate what $\min W$ is.  What you did is you calculated what $\min W$ was.  That took some hard calculations but it showed that $W$ was not empty.  What your professor did was must show $1-k \in W_k$ so $W_k$ is not empty.  Showing $1-k \in W_k$ was incredibly easy.

Comment: "It could be that my condition is the 'optimal' one and that the other is an approximation "  It's not an "approximation" because the professor isnt actually trying to solve or find any value.  S/He's just trying to find *A* value exist, s/he has no interest if finding any *specific* value and is not "approximating" any value.  If we discovered $n > 10^{31415}|K| \implies \frac 1n - n < K$ (which it *certainly* does) then we could use $N = 10^{31415}|K|$ (although such an absurd choice is tantamount to say "C'mon it's obvious").

Comment: "Then set N∈N so that N>1−K"  and "I'm not able to understand how N>1−K"  Maybe your concern is you are assuming that $N$ is a value that was predetermined and the professor is claiming that predetermined number is $> 1-K$.  That's not what the professor is saying. s/he is saying.  "We know $1-K$ is a value.  Let's pick any number larger than that.  No I will show that for any number larger than $1-K$ that number will have the property we need".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any $k$ let $W_k = \{N| n>N \implies \frac 1n-n < k\}$.  To show that $\frac 1n -n \to -\infty$ we must show that $W_k$ is not empty.  We do *not* have to calculate what $\min W_k$ is.  What you did is you calculated what $\min W_k$ was.  That took some hard calculations but it showed that $W_k$ was not empty.  What your professor did was must show $1-k \in W_k$ so $W_k$ is not empty.  Showing $1-k \in W_k$ was incredibly easy.

Both show that $\frac 1n-n \to -\infty$.

Note $\sqrt{\frac {k^2}4 + 1} -\frac k2 < 1-k$.  So if $n > 1-k > \sqrt{\frac {k^2}4 + 1} -\frac k2$ they both imply $\frac 1n - n < K$.

.........

No one cares about the optimal value.  For every $K$ there an $N$ so that $n> N$ will imply $n-\frac 1n < K$.  Which means that for any $\mathscr N >N$ we will also have $n > \mathscr N$ then $n > N$ so $n-\frac 1n < K$.

Now *NOBODY* cares about finding the *smallest* possible such $N$, because finding *ANY* such $\mathscr N$ will do.

Finding the *smallest* possible such $N$ is hard:

($\frac 1n - n) \le K$ so $n^2 +Kn -1\le 0$ so $n^2 + Kn +(\frac {K^2}4) \le 1+ (\frac {K^2}4)$  etc....$n < \sqrt{\frac {k^2}4 + 1} -\frac k2$ so if $N = \sqrt{\frac {k^2}4 + 1} -\frac k2$ we ar good.

But finding *any* is easy:

If $n >1$ then $\frac 1n < 1$ so $\frac 1n - n < 1 - n$ so if $1-n < K$  then $\frac 1n - n < 1-n < K$ and so if we let $\mathscr N = 1-K$ (assuming $K< 0$) then if $n > \mathscr N \implies n > 1-K \implies -n < K-1 \implies \frac 1n -n < 1 - n < K$.

Now admitted $\mathscr N$ might not be the smallest such number with the the property that $n > \mathscr N\implies \frac 1n - n < K$, and indeed $\mathscr N > N$ and $N$ also has the property, but.... who cares?  No one *ASKED* for the smallest such number.  And we don't care *when* $\frac 1n -n$ passes "the point of no return".

We just want to show $\frac 1n - n \to -\infty$.  And we can show that with any $\mathscr N \ge N$.

Comment: Could you elaborate on why $$n>1$$? Also, if this is feasible, what are the implications on the proof itself?

Comment: $n\to \infty$.   We care what $n$ does *as it gets "big"*.  So we don't care what it does when $n < 1$.  Also $n \in \mathbb N$ so $n \ge 1$.  All right.  Maybe I should have use $\ge$ and avoid  the whole issue.  But the issue doesn't matter.  Had it beent $\frac 1{n-7.3} - n$ then principal is the same.  We need an $N$ so that $n\ge N$ gives our result.  If we have $N \ge 8$ we can say that if $n \ge N \ge 8$ then we can assume $n\ge 8$.  We don't care about $n < 8$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $x_n = \frac{1}{n}-n$ for all $ n \geqslant 1$.  The objective then is to show that for any negative $K$, no matter how large, all $x_n$ after some point will be less than $K$. We use negative $K$ since we want to show $x_n \to -\infty$.  That is what the statement $x_n \to -\infty$ as $n \to \infty$ means.

It amounts to saying for every $K < 0$ we can find $N$, dependent on $K$,  such that,
$$
x_n < K \quad\text{for all }n \geqslant N.
$$
But for given $K$ this is obtained by choosing a value for $N$ greater than the positive number $1-K$.  Then if $n \geqslant N$, by definition we have $n > 1 - K$ which means $-n \leqslant K-1$.  At the same time, $n$ is always greater than or equal to one, so $1/n$ is less than or equal to one.  We can add the two inequalities,
$$ 1/n \leqslant 1, \quad -n \leqslant K-1
$$
to get
$$ \frac{1}{n}-n \leq K.
$$

I hope that is what you are looking for.